# Is it safe to consume expired Perilla seed oil?

Tags: food-safety, oil, culinary-uses

My parents bought a few perilla seed oil that I had no awareness of and found that it is expired already by around 1 year 1 month.
I tried to smell it, it still smells good without any rancid odour.

Is it still safe to consume?

I have heard that it is extremely easy for perilla seed oil to oxidise.

If it is not safe to eat, then is it usable in somewhere else? As light oil? Or anything?
I just want to avoid throwing it out while it could be used in some other ways.

Comment: by the way: never throw oils down the toilet or kitchen drain, it causes terrible water contamination further down. Oils can be recycled.

Comment: Hi, it seems that you are not aware of the basics of food safety in the strict sense. Rancidity/oxidation is not part of it. Uses of food for nonculinary purposes is also offtopic. You say"expired", but it is very unusual to see expiration dates on oil, it is likely a best-by date. I am closing as a duplicate of a question that explains the difference. If it turns out that your bottle has an expiration date, you can edit to leave only that part for reopening - it would be then best to read the tag info on food safety to understand why answers won't address what you are asking now.

Comment: @rumtscho Thanks for answering, because it is in Korean language,  I cannot read but only the roman date value....

Comment: @Luciano, how should I recycle the oils?

Comment: if your city doesn't have a collection program you can cool it down and pour it into a closed container (milk carton, plastic bag) and then into the garbage bin. Check some ideas here https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-do-i-dispose-of-used-cooking-oil-908995